# I am trying to understand the computer authentication process. what is the speed of password authentication process?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords

at what speed a particular computer can process an authentication password.also how to determine the speed it would take to test common password candidate lists, such as a list of 100 or 1000 popular passwords

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really confusing. 
Basically all algorithms have Time Complexity as a measure of their speed. But when it comes to program and softwares it's really a factor of multiple things. Nobody here can't claim that he/she has a measured speed. It even changes based on the operating system let alone hardware and other things. 
If you want to bypass a linux or windows auth, you really need to access root and remove auth. You can find tutorials on it. And if it's a server kind of thing that you want to do a library attack on, the networking speed to transfer packets affects the speed too.